# Segmentation model is producing NaNs as an output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nan, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform kidney and kidney tumor segmentation on kits19 dataset with use of u-net.
I am loading every case (3D data), MinMaxScaling them and then generating batches of 8, same with validation data. There is no preprocessing other than scaling. Then i'm feeding data to u-net with batch normalization after every conv layer. And doing amount of epochs as in this code:

```
NAME = "unet_without_edge_detection_with_batch_norm_{}".format(int(time.time()))

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME)),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='saved_models/checkpoints/{}'.format(NAME),
        save_weights_only=False, monitor='val_acc', mode='max', save_best_only=False)
    ]

# '------lists data points for train and validation'
# deleting broken cases
case_numbers = np.delete(np.arange(0, 209, 1), [158, 159, 170, 202])
case_numbers_val = case_numbers[179:]
case_numbers_train = case_numbers[:179]

batch_size = 8
data_size = 38650
val_data_size = 4520
results = model.fit(
    trainGenerator(case_numbers_train, batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch = int(np.floor( data_size / (batch_size) )),
    epochs = 16,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    verbose = 1,
    validation_data = validationGenerator(case_numbers_val, batch_size),
    validation_steps = int(np.floor( val_data_size / (batch_size) ))
    )

model.save('saved_models\model_from_{}'.format(time.time()))
```

During training loss suddenly drops to 1.1921e-7 and stays that way while accuracy fluctuates around 0.99 (which i guess is ok since most of doesn't contain any kidney).
When i'm trying to predict something with that model it outputs array of NaNs.

Here is summary of network(i use relu in all layers and sigmoid on output):

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 512, 512, 1) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 512, 512, 1)  0           input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 512, 512, 16) 160         lambda[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 512, 512, 16) 64          conv2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 512, 512, 16) 0           batch_normalization[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 512, 512, 16) 2320        dropout[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 512, 512, 16) 64          conv2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 256, 256, 16) 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 32) 4640        max_pooling2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 32) 9248        dropout_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 64) 18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 64) 36928       dropout_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 128)  147584      dropout_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_7[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 256)  1024        conv2d_8[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 256)  590080      dropout_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 256)  1024        conv2d_9[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTranspo (None, 64, 64, 128)  131200      batch_normalization_9[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose[0][0]
                                                                 batch_normalization_7[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 128)  295040      concatenate[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_10[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 128)  147584      dropout_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         conv2d_11[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 128, 128, 64) 32832       batch_normalization_11[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]
                                                                 batch_normalization_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 64) 73792       concatenate_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_12[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 64) 36928       dropout_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         conv2d_13[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 256, 256, 32) 8224        batch_normalization_13[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]
                                                                 batch_normalization_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32) 18464       concatenate_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_14[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           batch_normalization_14[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32) 9248        dropout_7[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 32) 128         conv2d_15[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 512, 512, 16) 2064        batch_normalization_15[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 512, 512, 32) 0           conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]
                                                                 batch_normalization_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 16) 4624        concatenate_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 512, 512, 16) 64          conv2d_16[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)             (None, 512, 512, 16) 0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 16) 2320        dropout_8[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 512, 512, 16) 64          conv2d_17[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 3)  51          batch_normalization_17[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,946,739
Trainable params: 1,943,795
Non-trainable params: 2,944
```

```
def soft_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-6): 
    axes = tuple(range(1, len(y_pred.shape)-1)) 
    numerator = 2. * np.sum(y_pred * y_true, axes)
    denominator = np.sum(np.square(y_pred) + np.square(y_true), axes)

    return 1 - np.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss =['categorical_crossentropy', soft_dice_loss], metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And here is generator:

```
def trainGenerator(case_nums, batch_size):
    #takes data from begining of data set to 
    while True:
        for case_num in case_nums:
            volume, segmentation = load_case(case_num)
            #preprocessing input
            X_file = preprocess_X(volume)
            y_file = preprocess_y(segmentation)
            L = X_file.shape[0]
            batch_start = 0
            batch_end = batch_size
            while batch_start < L:
                limit = min(batch_end, L)
                X = X_file[batch_start:limit, :, :, :]
                y = y_file[batch_start:limit, :, :, :]

                yield (X.astype(np.float32), y.astype(np.float32))            
                batch_start += batch_size   
                batch_end += batch_size

            if case_num == case_nums[-1]:
                # breaks loop so it starts again infinietly
                break
```

I tried to change activation function on output layer to softmax and tanh, optimizer and tried without bash normalization, and it didn't change anything.
What could be the issue since there is no nans in the data?
I use Tensorflow 2.2.0

Comment: Is this a known network ?

Comment: It's a U-net with 512x512x1 input, but i added few batch normalization layers in it

Comment: @Stsh4lson did you check if `denominator = np.sum(np.square(y_pred) + np.square(y_true), axes)` (in some cases) is zero or not?

Comment: @BelalHomaidan denominator indeed becomes zero at one point, thank you. I'll try to modify it.